# Missing shape reference even though shape exists

Tags: python

I have this Python code:

```py
cos = ibm_boto3.client('s3',
                       verify=False,
                       ibm_api_key_id=api_key,
                       ibm_service_instance_id=service_instance_id,
                       ibm_auth_endpoint=auth_endpoint,
                       config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
                       endpoint_url=service_endpoint)

response = cos.list_buckets(IBMServiceInstanceId=service_instance_id)

print('Response %s' % response)
```

It gives me this error(Note. Some of the trace has been removed):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_botocore/model.py", line 588, in resolve_shape_ref
    shape_name = member_traits.pop('shape')
KeyError: 'shape'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listing.py", line 21, in <module>
    response2 = cos.list_buckets(IBMServiceInstanceId=service_instance_id)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_botocore/model.py", line 187, in members
shape_members[name] = self._resolve_shape_ref(shape_ref)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_botocore/model.py", line 164, in _resolve_shape_ref
return self._shape_resolver.resolve_shape_ref(shape_ref)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_botocore/model.py", line 591, in resolve_shape_ref
    "Invalid model, missing shape reference: %s" % shape_ref)
ibm_botocore.model.InvalidShapeReferenceError: Invalid model, missing shape reference: OrderedDict([('location', 'header'), ('locationName', 'Ibm-Service-Instance-Id')])
```

I checked the shape and the list_buckets seems to be there. I'm not sure what else I need to check. Can anybody advice where the issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list_buckets` wasn't configured correctly on the device. Once configured I was able to perform the operation.